# get svg code in highchart directive with angular js

Tags: svg, highcharts, angularjs-directive

in normal highchart i get svg code with code like this

```
var chart = $('#container').highcharts()
svg = chart.getSVG();
```

So, how can i get svg code with this highchart directive in angular js???
i try like normal code but i didn't get `svg` code.
i use this directive for my highchart

```
https://github.com/rootux/angular-highcharts-directive
```

and this my code in controller.js

```
$scope.chartLogisticGIGR = {
                options: {
                    tooltip: {
                        shared: true
                    }
                },
                xAxis: { // Primary xAxis
                    categories: $scope.nameMonths,
                    title: {
                        text: 'Month'
                    },
                    labels: {
                        enabled: true
                    },
                    min:0
                },


                yAxis: [{ // Primary yAxis
                    title: {
                        text: 'GI / GR in IDR'
                    },

                    labels: {
                        formatter: function () {
                            return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.value / 1000000,'0') + ' mil';
                        }
                    }
                }, { // Secondary yAxis
                    title: {
                        text: 'Balance'
                    },

                    labels: {
                        formatter: function () {
                            return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.value / 1000000,'0') + ' mil';
                        }
                    },
                }],




                series: [{
                            name: 'AGP - Goods Receipt',
                            type: 'column',
                            stacking: 'normal',
                            stack: '1',

                            data: $scope.dataLogisticGIGR_AGP_GR,
                            color: $rootScope.getColor('AGP Ext'),
                            tooltip: {
                                pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}: {point.y:,.0f}</span><br/>'
                            }
                        },{
                            name: 'AGP - Goods Issue',
                            type: 'column',
                            stacking: 'normal',
                            stack: '1',
                            data: $scope.dataLogisticGIGR_AGP_GI,
                            color: $rootScope.getColor('AGP Int'),
                            tooltip: {
                                pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}: {point.y:,.0f}</span><br/>'
                            }
                        },{
                            name: 'AGP - Balance',
                            type: 'spline',
                            data: $scope.dataLogisticGIGR_AGP_Balance,
                            color: $rootScope.getColor('AI 2'),
                            tooltip: {
                                pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}: {point.y:,.0f}</span><br/>'
                            }
                        },{
                            name: 'AI - Goods Receipt',
                            type: 'column',
                            stacking: 'normal',
                            stack: '3',
                            data: $scope.dataLogisticGIGR_AI_GR,
                            color: $rootScope.getColor('AI'),
                            tooltip: {
                                pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}: {point.y:,.0f}</span><br/>'
                            }
                        },{
                            name: 'AI - Goods Issue',
                            type: 'column',
                            stacking: 'normal',
                            stack: '3',
                            data: $scope.dataLogisticGIGR_AI_GI,
                            color: $rootScope.getColor('AP 2'),
                            tooltip: {
                                pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}: {point.y:,.0f}</span><br/>'
                            }
                        },{
                            name: 'AI - Balance',
                            type: 'spline',
                            data: $scope.dataLogisticGIGR_AI_Balance,
                            color: $rootScope.getColor('AP'),
                            tooltip: {
                                pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}: {point.y:,.0f}</span><br/>'
                            }
                        }],
                title: {
                    text: ''
                },
                loading: false
            };
```

in this is my code in directive highchart

```
'use strict';

angular.module('chartsExample.directives',[])

.directive('chart', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<div></div>',
    scope: {
        chartData: "=value"
    },
    transclude:true,
    replace: true,

    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      var chartsDefaults = {
        chart: {
          renderTo: element[0],
          type: attrs.type || null,
          height: attrs.height || null,
          width: attrs.width || null
        }
      };

        //Update when charts data changes
        scope.$watch(function() { return scope.chartData; }, function(value) {
          if(!value) return;
            // We need deep copy in order to NOT override original chart object.
            // This allows us to override chart data member and still the keep
            // our original renderTo will be the same
            var newSettings = {};
            angular.extend(newSettings, chartsDefaults, scope.chartData);
            var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(newSettings);
        });
      }
    };

});
```

Thank's....

Comment: In general, when you use this directive what should happen, because ou need to have rendererd char tot use getSVG() in case when one directive return you a chart, second should return svg or something different?

Comment: i have added my directive highchart code  in there... can you help me??? :D

Comment: Can you explian how it should work ? I mean what shoudl happend when you use this directive, becasue I not see a getSVG in any place in your code. Please explain.